# how to split a javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

I trying to make a list in which it has a description field box in which I am getting a description Output...

This is my Javascript code In which I need to split the description function.

How to split the function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#selectedid").change(function() {
        var selectedid = $(this).val();
        $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/todos/"+selectedid, function(data){
                $("#description").val(data.description);    
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just move `$("#description").val(data.description);` into separate function and pass data.description as param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#selectedid").change(function() {
    var url = 'http://localhost:8080/todos/' + $(this).val();
    $.getJSON(url, setDescription);
});

function setDescription(data) {
    $("#description").val(data.description);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the functions as you want like the following callback functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectedid").change(function() {
    var selectedid = $(this).val();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/todos/" + selectedid;
    sendGet(url, handleResponse);
  }
  
  function sendGet(url, callback) {
    $.getJSON(url, callback);
  }
  
  function handleResponse(data) {
    $("#description").val(data.description);
  }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#selectedid").change(function() {
    var selectedid = $(this).val();
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/todos/" + selectedid;
    $.getJSON(url, handleResponse);
  }
  
  function handleResponse(data) {
    $("#description").val(data.description);
  }
});
```